# Parsing the Table Name from queries in Java

Tags: java, database, list, parsing

https://github.com/FoundationDB/sql-parser

How to use this library to parse a query (can be very complex) and retrieve the list of every table in that query.

The queries can be long and complex for example :

```
SELECT LINK.instance_id, 
       LINK.fk_rte_pnt_start, 
       LINK.fk_rte_pnt_end, 
       LINK.depart_time_local_expect, 
       LINK.arrvl_time_local_expect, 
       LINK.depart_time_utc_expctd, 
       LINK.arrvl_time_utc_expctd, 
       LINK.fk_mepc_trnsprt_mode, 
       LINK.mepc_link_id, 
       LINK.rkst_carrier_cd, 
       LINK.water_land_mode, 
       LINK.fk_rkstves_part_vehicle, 
       LINK.rkstves_part_vehicle, 
       LINK.vehicle_voyg_num, 
       LINK.fk_route, 
       LINK.routng_type, 
       LINK.is_out_of_cntrct_scope, 
       STRT.point_seq, 
       STRT.fk_geo_site DEP_SITE_CD, 
       ENDP.fk_geo_site ARR_SITE_CD, 
       STRT.geo_site    DEP_SITE_CD_X, 
       ENDP.geo_site    ARR_SITE_CD_X 
FROM   (SELECT instance_id, 
               fk_rte_pnt_start, 
               fk_rte_pnt_end, 
               depart_time_local_expect, 
               arrvl_time_local_expect, 
               depart_time_utc_expctd, 
               arrvl_time_utc_expctd, 
               fk_mepc_trnsprt_mode, 
               mepc_link_id, 
               rkst_carrier_cd, 
               water_land_mode, 
               fk_rkstves_part_vehicle, 
               rkstves_part_vehicle, 
               vehicle_voyg_num, 
               fk_route, 
               routng_type, 
               is_out_of_cntrct_scope 
        FROM   codsbrk.gcss_route_link 
        WHERE  fk_route = ?) LINK 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN codsbrk.gcss_route_point STRT 
                    ON STRT.instance_id = LINK.fk_rte_pnt_start 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN codsbrk.gcss_route_point ENDP 
                    ON ENDP.instance_id = LINK.fk_rte_pnt_end 
ORDER  BY STRT.point_seq 
WITH UR
```

and

```
SELECT MIRL.invoice_req_line_id, 
       MIRL.collection_office, 
       MIRL.prepaid_collect, 
       MIRL.item_code, 
       MIRL.line_amount_quoted, 
       MIRL.currency_code, 
       MIRL.unit_price_quoted, 
       MIRL.quantity, 
       MIRL.owner_of_income 
FROM   codsbrk.mlis_invoice MIR 
       INNER JOIN codsbrk.mlis_invoice_line MIRL 
               ON MIR.tpdoc_no = MIRL.tpdoc_no 
                  AND MIR.invoice_req_id = MIRL.invoice_req_id 
WHERE  MIR.tpdoc_no = ? 
       AND MIR.invoice_status = ? 
WITH UR
```

Comment: Is there anything in the **sql-parser** documentation that is unclear? What have you tried so far, and what does not work?

Comment: Have tried this code, which simply parses the fromList, and not the join part(s) if any... http://pastebin.com/qfWGiYqJ here is the code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was provided by Nathan Williams

code here : https://gist.github.com/nathanlws/f71000943777297c7cfb

can be found here !!!
http://community.foundationdb.com/questions/4418/parsing-the-table-names-from-complex-queries.html#answer-4419

Quoting Nathan Williams :
Switching to looking for FromTable will allow you to catch the remaining tables that aren't directly in the FromList (e.g. subqueries, joins).

```
import com.foundationdb.sql.parser.*;
import com.foundationdb.sql.StandardException;

public class TableFinder {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SQLParser parser = new SQLParser();
        for(String sql : args) {
            StatementNode node = parser.parseStatement(sql);
            node.accept(new FromTablePrinter());
        }
    }

    public static class FromTablePrinter implements Visitor {
        public Visitable visit(Visitable node) throws StandardException {
            if(node instanceof FromTable) {
                FromTable ft = (FromTable)node;
                TableName name = ft.getOrigTableName();
                String alias = ft.getCorrelationName();
                if(name != null) {
                    System.out.print(name);
                    if(alias != null) {
                        System.out.print(" AS " + alias);
                    }
                    System.out.println();
                } else if (alias != null) {
                    String type = node.getClass().getSimpleName();
                    System.out.println(type + " AS " + alias);
                }
            }
            return node;
        };

        public boolean visitChildrenFirst(Visitable node) {
            return false;
        }

        public boolean stopTraversal() {
            return false;
        }

        public boolean skipChildren(Visitable node) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, it is better to provide the actual information here and not just a link. [Link-only answers are not considered good answers and will probably be deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).